# find command fusses on -exec arg

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to build and run a `find` command from a script. But I get a very cryptic error message from `find`. The following basically sums up how I build the command line and run it

```
$ xx="find . -name 'p*' -mmin +10 -exec echo {} \\;"
$ echo "$xx" #.....and I get the same print from echo $xx
find . -name 'p*' -mmin +10 -exec echo {} \;
$ $xx
find: missing argument to `-exec'
$ find . -name 'p*' -mmin +10 -exec echo {} \;
./p2.sh
./p1.sh
$ read xx
find . -name 'p*' -mmin +2 -exec echo {} \\;
$ $xx
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I am stuck and will appreciate your help. I am also wondering what's causing this. I am using bash 3.2.51 on SLES.

The actual command I want to execute is a little bit longer but I used `echo` here just to illustrate.

Thanks
Dinesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to store complicated commands in bash variables and then evaluate the variables pretty well never works.

If you need to build a command in pieces, use an array. See this useful Bash FAQ: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Here's the basic strategy:

```
# Make an array
declare -a findcmd=(find .)
# Add some arguments
findcmd+=(-name 'p*')
findcmd+=(-mmin +10)
findcmd+=(-exec echo {} \;)
# Run the command
"${findcmd[@]}"
```

You need to understand how bash quoting works. Remember that the quoting (and de-quoting) *only happens once*, when you type the command (or when bash reads it from a script file). Quotes which get into the values of variables are just ordinary characters.

If you're experimenting with `set -x`, remember also that `set -x` *inserts quotes* in order to remove ambiguities. These quotes *are not part of the variables*. While that is clearly essential, it seems to be confusing to programmers who are not familiar with the bash execution model.